# Method to calculate score in a go game

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I'm currently programming a go game, and I'm struggling with some aspect of the game, especially how to handle the end game, how to count **points** and how to detect **dead stones** ?

I thought of doing a BFS on an **empty intersection** (*to get all the empty intersections connected*) and if all the stones connected to the BFS (*Group of empty intersections*) are of one color, **then** give that score to the player. If the stones connected are of both color, then the territory is neutral.

But I'm unable to detect dead stones on ennemy territory. Is there a trick, algorithm to detect these stones ?

*In this image if I run the BFS on the red dot it will be neutral territory, while the desired behaviour is to detect the two dead stones and give the score to white*

[image: Image of dead stones]

Comment: Just to remember, a group is dead if it does not have at least 2 eyes ? I it true ?

Comment: well, if it's not a seki,  you are right (I'm not go expert but seems right).